# Cloning a Wine prefix?

Tags: wine

I have a Wine prefix I've built up for running an application, with a lot of assorted services and frameworks that were a hassle to install, all so I can install this one program.

However, that setup is likely useful to other prefixes that use those same frameworks.

I've looked, and I've seen guides for moving a prefix from one computer to another, but is there an good way to clone a prefix locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy Wine prefixes to clone them:

```
cp -a "${WINEPREFIX}" /path/to/new/prefix
```

Then

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/new/prefix wine ...
```

will run programs in your new prefix.

This doesn’t take care of any desktop entries in `${XDG_DATA_HOME}/applications/wine/...` (`~/.local/share/applications/wine/...`); you might want to copy them under new names, with corrected prefixes.